# Jhipster: two different angular applications

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, jhipster

In jhipster, there is an angular application which is configured by angular-cli.json and webpack to be built and served in the `build/www/` folder.

In many cases I find that while jhipster provides a good scaffolding and crud managing application which is suited for a backend, there is no possibility to start a second application which has a frontend and the benefit of using the same entities generated by jHipster and available to the admin application through the full stack of the generator from angular through the database.

Is anyone able to provide a solution to have two different applications under `/webapp`? E.g. (`webapp/app` and `webapp/lab`).

I am able to use another routing to angular but I'd like to have two different application under the `apps` array in angular-cli.json.

I would like the applications to be built and treated as separated angular applications. But so far I wasn't able to do it.

Any help is truly appreciated, as long as it is a detailed explanation on how to map the second application and to be able to maintain both.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take a look at [this angular CLI doc](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/multiple-apps.md)

This will get you set up with multiple apps with the CLI. If you want to link from one app to another and serve them both at the same time you can add scripts to your `package.json` like so :

```
"start": "ng serve --app app1",
"start:app2": "ng serve --app app2 --port 4201"
```

where `app` and `app2` are the names you declared in your `angular-cli.json` file

If you want to handle dynamix links between your apps you should also have an `environment.ts` and `environment-prod.ts` files where you will define your links :

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  APP: 'http://localhost:4200',
  APP2: 'http://localhost:4201'
}
```

so you can create links between your apps in both dev and prod

Comment: that's what I did, however I have this error:
```ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp
Module parse failed: /Users/superandrew/Documents/xcode/brainapp-new/src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp Unexpected token (2:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "name": "Brainapp",
|   "short_name": "Brainapp",
|   "icons": [
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 62:0-29
 @ multi ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts

```. Besides, the apps aren't built in /build/www when I launch ./gradle jhipster task

Comment: probably ng serve is not the way jhipster is supposed to work, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6050 so probably your advice is good, but I need to make it work with `yarn start`